# How to check a file is locked for writing in perl without actually locking it again?

Tags: linux, perl, file-locking, flock

How to check a file is locked for writing in perl. I don't want to use lock again and if it fails it tells that it is being locked by other processes.

```
flock (FILE, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB)
```

I don't want to use the above technique since it locks the file if it is not locked by other processes.

Comment: What's the problem with lock-and-release?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85994/how-to-list-processes-locking-file

Comment: I want child to write to file only when parent is done writing and lock is released from parent. How can i do that?
I want a condition like if the file is not locked then start writing to file.

Answer (score 4):

> *I want a condition like if the file is not locked then start writing to file.*

You said what you want to do when the file isn't locked, but you didn't say what you want to do when the file is locked. I presume you want to wait for it to become unlocked.

If so, use the following:

```
open(my $fh, ">>", $qfn) or die $!;
flock($fh, LOCK_EX) or die $!;
print($fh ...);
close($fh);
```

If you want to clear the file first, do the following after obtaining the lock:

```
truncate($fh, 0) or die $!;
```

Comment: Thank you for you comments.
I found the solution for this. I can check a file is locked using the Linux command "fuser -- <filename>". It returns process id if it is locked otherwise null. This can be used instead of trying for lock on locked file.